# Why the addToBackStack does not work when back button pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I was confused by it.

I hava a activity A, Fragment F1 and F2, when one button was clicked, I want to hide F1 and add the F2 to the same place and can go back to F1 by back button. So I did as below.

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.hide(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CHAT_LIST_FRAGMENT_TAG));
    transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, MessageListFragment.newInstance(username, false));
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

But when I pressed the back button, the activity finished instead of back to the F1. I tried to use replace, and the result is same.

Does the only solution is to override the onBackPress method?

---

### More

I tried the code like below.

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.repalce(R.id.content_frame, MessageListFragment.newInstance(username, false));
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: You shouldn't call `hide` on Fragment F1, just call `replace` with `addToBackStack` for F2.

Comment: I tried to call replace instead of add, but it does not work either.

Comment: By the other hand, The F1 is the main ui in my app, so I does not like to replace it due to the performance.

Comment: Just do what I said and don't call hide, only replace with `addToBackStack(null)`.

Comment: I comment the hide line and use replace instead of add, nothing changed.

Comment: Which version of Android? I think there's a bug in some versions where you have to do things one step at a time, like do the replace, commit, then do the add and commit again.

Comment: Are you using the support library?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `replace()` instead of `hide()` + `add()`. Here is corresponding [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions).

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, MessageListFragment.newInstance(username, false));
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Make sure you call super method if you override onBackPressed().

Comment: I call the super method, but I wonder override the method is must to achieve such a function or I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

This works. Probably, you need "getSupportFragmentManager" instead of yours getFragmentManager

NB! don't "addToBackStack" the root fragment, otherwise, it would end up with blank screen, when you click back, in attempt to close the app.

Comment: All fragment I used is android.app.Fragment, getSupportFragmentManager  causes lots of errors.